# Node.js module to fetch data from MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, module

I want to use an module to get and process data from my MongoDB database. (It should generate an object that represents my Express.js site's navbar)

I thought of doing something like this:

```js
var nav = { Home: "/" };
module.exports = function() {
  MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    fetchData(db, function(articles, categories) {
      combine(articles, categories, function(sitemap) {
        // I got the data. What now?
        console.log("NAV: ", nav);
      })
    });
  });
};

var fetchData = function(db, callback) {
  db.collection('articles').find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err);
    articles = result;
    db.collection('categories').find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      assert.equal(err);
      categories = result;
      db.close();
      callback(articles, categories);
    });
  });
};

var combine = function(articles, categories, callback) {
  categories.forEach(function(category) {
    nav[category.title] = {};
    articles.forEach(function(article) {
      if(article.category == category.name) {
        nav[category.title][article.title] = "link";
      }
    })
  });
  callback(nav);
};
```

As of line 6, I do have all data I need.

(An object, currenty like `{ Home: '/', Uncategorized: { 'Hello world!': 'link' } }`)

But since I'm in an anonymous function, I don't know how to return that value. I mean, `return` would just return it the function that called it... And in the end, MongoClient.connect would receive my data.

If I set a variable instead, it would be set as `module.exports` returned before Node can even query the data from the database, right?

What can I do in order to make this work?

It should result in some kind of function, like

```js
var nav = require('nav');
console.log(nav());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can always return the desired data by using callbacks.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner How? I'm new to Node.js, sorry.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Hopefully correct as I don't have an ability to test it right now. Write a comment if you encounter any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another callback:

```
var nav = { Home: "/" };
module.exports = function(cb) {
    MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        fetchData(db, function(articles, categories) {
            combine(articles, categories, function(sitemap) {
                cb(sitemap);
            })
        });
    })
});
```

And then use this way:

```
var nav = require('nav');
nav(function(sitemap){ console.log(sitemap); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongoose module or monk module. These modules have been tested properly .

Just use

> npm install mongoose or monk

Comment: That should still work with the official module, somehow. If I can't find an solution, I'll try mongoose. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion about mongoose is great and you can look into it, however I think you've already done the job with the fetching of the data from the db. You just need to access it in your main node flow.

You can try this:

```
module.exports.generateNav = function() {
  MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    var output = fetchData(db, function(articles, categories) {
      combine(articles, categories, function(sitemap) {

      })
    });
    return (output);
  });
};
```

And then in your main application you can call it in the following way:

```
var nav = require('nav');
navigation = nav.generateNav();
console.log(navigation);
```

Comment: That was also my idea.
But, you seem to not really understand my problem... If I add a return statement to fetchData, the data is passed to `db.collection('categories').find({}).toArray`, which does not make any sense...

Comment: `fetchData` function is asynchronous. I hardly see that work the way you written that here. `output` will be most likely `undefined`.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner Correct.